# WHERE with several ANDed conditions filters as expected but using just one of them unexpectedly returns all rows

Tags: mysql, where-clause, inner-join

I tried to return some of the rows in table `service`:

```
SELECT ps.post_name as post, c.cname, p.place, s.date_from,
    s.date_to, e.emp_name as employee, s.court, s.place
FROM `service` s 
INNER JOIN `employee` e ON s.empno = e.empno
INNER JOIN `posts` ps ON s.post = ps.code
INNER JOIN `court` c ON s.court = c.code
INNER JOIN `place` p ON s.place = p.code
WHERE s.court=13 AND s.place=7 AND s.date_to='0000-00-00'
ORDER BY s.post
```

This works with results as expected with various values.  But when I remove `s.court=13` and `s.place=7` and have `WHERE s.date_to='0000-00-00'` it fails and shows all the records in `service`.  I tried various ways, including with inner join and left join, but in vain.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please post some sample data along with actual and expected results.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score -2):

check your sql_mode:   SELECT @@sql_mode;

especially for NO_ZERO_DATE, which affects how MySQL interprets ‘0000-00-00’ dates

Change '0000 00 00' to other non zero data

Comment: Change it how? What other value would yield the same intended result? And he doesn't have `0000 00 00`: he has `0000-00-00`.

Comment: you can change it to  '2024 01 01' or  another one , like this: update `service` set  date_to='2024-01-01' where date_to='0000-00-00' and  change your sql to :  SELECT ps.post_name as post, c.cname, p.place, s.date_from,
    s.date_to, e.emp_name as employee, s.court, s.place
FROM `service` s 
INNER JOIN `employee` e ON s.empno = e.empno
INNER JOIN `posts` ps ON s.post = ps.code
INNER JOIN `court` c ON s.court = c.code
INNER JOIN `place` p ON s.place = p.code
WHERE  s.date_to='2024-01-01'
ORDER BY s.post

Comment: This is very unclear. It also doesn't say how the things you mention could cause the problem. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. Use standard spelling & punctuation. Read the edit help re formatting including special characters. [answer] [Help]